# How to fit a Rust ZipArchive and ZipFile into a single Read-implementing struct, while dealing with lifetime and borrowing rules

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

This question could be asked in a few different ways but my end-goal is to encapsulate one file from a `ZipArchive` (Rust zip crate) into a struct called `ZipReader` that implements Read, like so:

```
struct ZipReader<R: Read + Seek> { ... }
impl<R: Read + Seek> ZipReader<R> {
    fn from(src: R, filename: &str) -> ZipReader<R> { ... }
}
impl <R: Read + Seek> Read for ZipReader<R> { ... }
```

My effort to do so has involved constructing a new `ZipArchive` from the src stream, then using `ZipArchive.by_name(name)` to extract the `ZipFile<'a>` from which bytes may be read.

The issue I run into is that the `ZipFile<'a>` struct references the lifetime of the `&'a mut ZipArchive` from which it was constructed -- meaning the `ZipArchive` must remain in scope *and* remain mutably borrowed for the lifetime of the `ZipFile`.

This combination of constraints seems to make it impossible to encapsulate the zip in a new struct:

```
pub struct ZipReader<R: Read + Seek> {
    file: zip::read::ZipFile<'_>, // Have experimented with lifetimes here with no success
    archive: ZipArchive<R>,
}
impl <R: Read + Seek> ZipReader<R> {
    fn from(mut zip: R, name: &str) -> ZipReader<R> {
        let archive = ZipArchive::new(zip);
        let file = archive.by_name(name).unwrap();
        ZipReader {
            file: file,
            archive: archive.unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
impl <R: Read + Seek> Read for ZipReader<R> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.file.read(buf)
    }
}
```

I cannot move `file` alone into the returned `ZipReader` because `archive` will go out of scope, but I cannot move `archive` to `ZipReader` because it is borrowed by `file`.

It seems like modifying the zip crate and incorporating the `ZipFile` state into `ZipArchive` to eliminate the lifetime issue would be one way to solve the problem.  How could this be solved without modifying anyone else's code?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this safely without changing the `zip` crate. See [`owning_ref::OwningHandle`](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/struct.OwningHandle.html) for a partial solution to this kind of problem (but not super helpful in your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Coder-256 mentioned, `owning_ref::OwningHandle` provides functionality to solve the borrowing problem, but not the lifetime problem.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/issues/22) on the repo for [`owning_ref`](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html) that describes an equivalent situation and requests additional functionality to solve it, but it has been open since 2017 with no resolution.

I ended up [modifying the zip crate](https://github.com/cjgriscom/zip-rs/commit/3caeb74cc3663a85f5f5e81a79d5f14a534f88d1) to transfer ownership of the underlying stream instead of holding the reference to the ZipArchive.  This is satisfactory enough for my purposes, but a solution like `owning_ref` seems to be the correct approach for this type of problem.

Update: It seems the `ouroboros` crate solves this problem in a more generic way, see: [Open a single file from a ZIP archive and pass on as Read instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823680/open-a-single-file-from-a-zip-archive-and-pass-on-as-read-instance)