# Open a single file from a ZIP archive and pass on as Read instance

Tags: rust

I am using the [zip crate](https://docs.rs/zip/0.5.12/zip/read/struct.ZipArchive.html) to read data from ZIP archives:

```rust
impl<R: Read + Seek> ZipArchive<R> {
  pub fn new(reader: R) -> ZipResult<ZipArchive<R>> {...}
  pub fn by_name<'a>(&'a mut self, name: &str) -> ZipResult<ZipFile<'a>> {...}
  ...
}
```

I need to implement a function that given the name of a ZIP archive and the name of a contained file returns an instance of [`std::io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html). Is this possible?

`ZipFile` does implement `Read`, but unfortunately it retains a reference to the ZipArchive and I can't find a way to build a struct that takes ownership of both the `ZipArchive` and `ZipFile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the `zip` crate requires a self-referential struct for such usage. Self-referential structs are not allowed by the borrow checker, but you can avoid the underlying problem by heap-allocating `ZipArchive` to prevent it from moving.

Even with the use of `Box` for heap allocation, the borrow checker still won't accept the resulting code because it doesn't special-case `Box`, and because it can't prove that some code won't move the object out of the box. To make it compile you'll need to use unsafe transmute to decouple the borrow of `ZipFile` from the archive. It will be up to you to maintain the invariants: that `ZipArchive` doesn't move and that `ZipFile` gets destroyed before `ZipArchive`. Fortunately the code is short, so it should be easy to review for correctness.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
pub fn read_zip(file_name: &str, member_name: &str) -> ZipResult<impl std::io::Read> {
    struct ZipReader {
        // actually has lifetime of `archive`
        // declared first so it's droped before `archive`
        reader: ZipFile<'static>,
        #[allow(dead_code)]
        // safety: we must never move out of this box as long as reader is alive
        archive: Box<ZipArchive<BufReader<File>>>,
    }

    impl Read for ZipReader {
        fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
            self.reader.read(buf)
        }
    }

    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(file_name)?);

    // Safety: We must never move `archive` out of its Box, and we must destroy
    // `reader` before `archive`.  The first is ensured by never giving access to
    // the box, and the second by the drop order guarantees documented by Rust.
    let mut archive = Box::new(ZipArchive::new(file)?);
    let reader = archive.by_name(member_name)?;
    let reader = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(reader) };

    Ok(ZipReader { archive, reader })
}
```

The above code should be sound even though we lie to the borrow checker about the lifetime of the reference. First, the lie is consistent with the premise of the `'static` bound: it is indeed possible to indefinitely extend the lifetime of `ZipRead` without invalidating the reference. (This is what the borrow checker cannot yet prove on its own.) Secondly, Rust's lifetime analysis never affects code generation, it only validates the code, thus our "lie" cannot cause the code to miscompile.

If you're ok with an external dependency, you can use [`ouroboros`](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros) to avoid unsafe (or rather confine it to the code generated by its proc macro). That way the code you write should be sound, providing there are no issues in ouroboros. This is what it would look like:

```
pub fn read_zip(file_name: &str, member_name: &str) -> ZipResult<impl std::io::Read> {
    #[ouroboros::self_referencing]
    struct ZipReader {
        archive: ZipArchive<BufReader<File>>,
        #[borrows(mut archive)]
        #[not_covariant]
        reader: ZipFile<'this>,
    }

    impl Read for ZipReader {
        fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
            self.with_reader_mut(|reader| reader.read(buf))
        }
    }

    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(file_name)?);
    let archive = ZipArchive::new(file)?;
    // ZipReaderBuilder and ZipReaderTryBuilder are generated by ouroboros.
    ZipReaderTryBuilder {
        archive,
        reader_builder: |archive| archive.by_name(member_name),
    }
    .try_build()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @user4815162342, this indeed solved my problem! It's unfortunate that this requires unsafe code.

I've changed the solution to rely on member order of the struct instead of implementing `Drop` manually. AIU that should be just as safe.

Comment: @MForster The answer now includes a solution that uses ouroboros to avoid (direct) unsafe.