# Is there any way to not link the lifetime of the iterator to the struct?

Tags: filter, rust, iterator, traits, lifetime

I am trying to implement a filter function which receives an iterator to a vector and returns an iterator with the filter. Is there any way by which I don't link the lifetime of the iterator to the struct? I am able to make it work by making lifetime of iterator depend on the struct but that is not what I intend to do.

Here is a simplified code:

```
struct Structure {
    low: i32,
}

impl Structure {
    pub fn find_low<'a>(
        &mut self,
        packets: impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32> {
        packets.filter(|packet| **packet < self.low)
    }

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Structure { low: 10 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let strct = Structure::new();
    let vec = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13];
    let mut it = strct.find_low(vec.iter());
    assert_eq!(it.next().unwrap(), &vec[0]);
}
```

By doing so, I get an error

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
7 |         &mut self,
  |         --------- hidden type `Filter<impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:24: 10:52]>` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
8 |         packets: impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>,
9 |     ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32> {
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: to declare that the `impl Trait` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
  |
9 |     ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32> + '_ {
  |                                        ++++
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3ffd96d9c2bdae0199da24bbac760054)

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67901675 ([Applied to your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf6c8a3d030cddaed86f87404ab0db52))

Comment: Your returned iterator references `self.low`, which means that it **should** incorporate the lifetime of `self`. You could [copy the value of `low` into the closure](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0281a359295d09994bf88abb21127284).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way not to link the lifetime of the returned iterator to that of the reference to `self`: you need to move the data the filtering closure needs into the closure so that it doesn't reference it.  To accomplish this, copy `self.low` into a local variable and move it into the closure.

Once you fix this, you will uncover a second problem: your `main()` as written can't invoke `strct.find_low()` as `strct` is not declared `mut` -- but it shouldn't need to be.  `find_low` needlessly takes `self` as a mutable reference, when an immutable reference will do.  Replace `&mut self` with `&self`.

```
    pub fn find_low<'a>(
        &self,
        packets: impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32> {
        let low = self.low;
        packets.filter(move |packet| **packet < low)
    }
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2e4880823cf9ff02541bbd21aa82339))

An alternative to moving a copy of `self.low` into the closure is to restrict the lifetime of `&self` to include `'a` as well, though this *does* link the lifetime of the returned iterator to that of `Structure`.

```
    pub fn find_low<'a>(
        &'a self,
        packets: impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32>,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i32> {
        packets.filter(move |packet| **packet < self.low)
    }
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ceefdecd9b2f1bfbb02e4448cff77c89))

Comment: This works for the example posted. However, in the real code I am working with a redis connection inside the filter. Redis needs a mutable copy of connection (which is stored in the object) to do the SET operation. Hence, unable to create a copy.

Comment: @RichaJain Then you will need the second approach I gave in my answer, which requires that `*self` outlive the returned iterator, or else you'd need some way to clone `Structure` and have the closure take ownership of the clone.

Comment: Cannot do either since redis connection is a lazy_static mutex (so cannot clone), I would like to drop the redis keys in the end which is interfering with the lifetime

Comment: @RichaJain Then you'll have to post a new question that properly illustrates the new problem you're running into.

Comment: Sure, let me do that