# How do I box two objects whose lifetimes are linked?

Tags: rust, parquet

I'm trying to use the `parquet` library to create a record iterator object in a function that can be iterated using my own trait called `RecordIterator`. It looks like this:

```
    fn blah(dataset_info: DatasetInfo, file: File) -> Result<Box<dyn RecordIterator<Item=Record>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let reader = SerializedFileReader::new(file).unwrap();
        let iter = (&reader).get_row_iter(None).unwrap();
        let column_type = *dataset_info.column_type.clone();
        let iterator = ParquetRecordIterator {
            iterator: iter,
            column_type: column_type,
            i: 0,
        };
        Ok(Box::new(iterator))
    }
```

The problem is that because iter has a lifetime attached to the SerializedFileReader variable it is created from, returning the ParquetRecordIterator (which implements the RecordIterator trait) object complains with an error saying:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `reader` [E0515]
```

I would ideally not like to break the abstraction here, so how would you suggest implementing this function? Effectively, I would like to break the lifetime link between the reader and the iterator, but not sure how best I could do that, or use a different parquet API to do this.

I've tried wrapping the file reader in a `Box::new`, hoping that the lifetimes would not be tied to an object in the heap, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

I've NOT tried any libraries to deal with self-referential structs because it doesn't seem like they're recommended, so I was hoping for a standard way to solve this.

I've NOT tried looking into other parquet libraries.

Comment: Can you put the reader itself in the `ParquetRecordIterator` and then provide an `iter(&self)` method?

Comment: Approaches presented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67828823/1600898) might be of use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a hard problem in Rust since you're essentially trying to create a [self-referential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) struct.

Fortunately for you, you don't need to solve this problem in general, since the library you're using provides direct support for this use-case: [`impl IntoIterator for SerializedFileReader<File>`](https://docs.rs/parquet/50.0.0/src/parquet/file/serialized_reader.rs.html#81-88). So:

```rust
    fn blah(dataset_info: DatasetInfo, file: File) -> Result<Box<dyn RecordIterator<Item=Record>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let reader = SerializedFileReader::new(file).unwrap();
        let iter = reader.into_iter();
        let column_type = *dataset_info.column_type.clone();
        let iterator = ParquetRecordIterator {
            iterator: iter,
            column_type: column_type,
            i: 0,
        };
        Ok(Box::new(iterator))
    }
```

Comment: This worked!!! Wow that's magic! Thank you so much! I wish I could give you 10 upvotes for such a great solution!